# Understanding the different versions of Kantorovich-Rubinstein Duality

Tags: duality-theorems, optimal-transport

In lecture notes and the book "Optimal Transport: old and new", the Kantorovich-Rubinstein Duality is presented as:

(K-R) Let $X=Y$ Polish, with $c:X \times X \to \overline{\mathbb R}$ lower-semicontinuous,
$\mu, \nu \in \mathcal P_1(X)$. Then
$$
\min_{\gamma \in \Pi(\mu,\nu)}\int_{X \times X} c(x,y)d\gamma = \sup\left\{
\int_X f d(\mu -\nu) :  ||f||_{Lip_1} \leq 1
\right\}
$$

Now, in the book Santambrogio, he does not prove the Kantorovich-Rubinstein Duality per-se, but he gives two theorems that together give something similar to the Kantorovich-Rubinstein.

**Thm. 1.42**: If $X, Y$ are Polish and $c:X \times Y \to \overline{\mathbb R}$ is l.s.c and bounded from below, then the duality formula $\min KP = \sup DP$.

**Prop. 3.1**: If $c: X \times X \to \mathbb R$ is a distance, then a function $u: X \to\mathbb R$ is $c$-concave if and only if it is Lipschitz continuous with constant less or equal to 1 with respect to distance $c$.

As is see it, this two results imply the Kantorovich-Rubinstein Duality, but wihtout the need of $\mu,\nu \in \mathcal P_1(X)$, in other words, there is no need for $\int_X |x| d\mu < +\infty$
and  $\int_X |y| d\mu < +\infty$.

Now, is my interpretation correct? Why is the $\mu,\nu \in \mathcal P_1(X)$ necessary instead of just $\mu,\nu \in \mathcal P(X)$. What am I missing?

Comment: Probably Santambrogio is assuming at some point something like compactness of $X$ in which case you don't need integrability assumptions on the marginals. If not however one typically imposes that assumption in order to ensure finiteness of $\int cd\gamma$.

Comment: Look that theorem 1.42 does not assume compactness, and neither does Prop 3.1

Comment: That it's not written down in the theorem doesn't mean it's not assumed. Santambrogio is often a little sloppy in his formulations.

Comment: I don't think it's the case in this instance. Because in the chapter he first proves in the Compact space, then moves on to Polish spaces.

Comment: In your expression of the K-R formula, the cost function $c(x,y)$ only appears on one side which strikes me as a typo. Did you mean the cost function to be exactly the metric?  Otherwise I can choose $c(x,y)=1$ to make the LHS constantly 1 and choose $f(x)=d(a,x)$,  $\mu = \delta_a$ and $\nu = \delta_b$ to make the RHS equal to $d(a,b)$.